# Search SQL db using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to search DB using **LINQ to SQL** and display it. I tried below code but it not showing record matching to criteria on console.

Here **Details is table name**

```
Detail detail = new Detail();

    Console.Write("\nEnter ID to Search Record :");
     int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     var searchbyId = from search in db.Details
                         where search.Id == id
                         select search;
     db.SubmitChanges();
     Console.WriteLine("\n Search Results \n");
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Id \t | Name \t | Last Name \n"));

     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} \t | {1} \t | {2} ",
                               detail.Id,detail.Name, detail.LastName));
```

**Newbie trying to learn LINQ**

Comment: What's `detail` here?

Comment: Why a SubmitChanges ? You don't update anything in db.

Comment: what's up with `db.SubmitChanges();`?

Comment: you never used searchbyId  object aftre assign the value

Comment: Just a newbie trying to learn LINQ

Comment: @Piyush It is specific question. Ia m trying to search record,so it is not random question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be Multiple Results having Same ID so Use `foreach`

```
Console.Write("\nEnter ID to Search Record :");
 int id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 var searchbyId = from search in db.Details
                     where search.Id == id
                     select search;

 Console.WriteLine("\n Search Results \n");
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Id \t | Name \t | Last Name \n"));

 foreach(var item in searchbyId )
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} \t | {1} \t | {2} ",
                           item.Id,detail.Name, item.LastName));
```

**[101 LINQ Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. Will accept it as answer soon

Comment: @Richa try 101 LINQ Samples those are best from MSDN

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like that:

```
Console.Write("\nEnter First Name :");
string id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
var searchbyId = from search in db.Details
                 where search.Id == id
                 select search;
Console.WriteLine("\n Search Results \n");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Id \t | Name \t | Last Name \n"));

foreach(var item in searchbyId )
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} \t | {1} \t | {2} ",
                       searchbyId.Id,detail.Name, searchbyId.LastName));
```